# Android: How to delete after so many characters?

Tags: java

I need to delete coma(,) after so many. Say there a string with 4 coma's "i , am , ok, today, hello" and i want to delete reset after 2 comans but leave the the text alone just delete comans after first 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it.

```
public string StripCommas(string str, int allowableCommas) {
    int comma;
    int found = 0;
    comma = str.indexOf(",");
    while (comma >= 0) {
        found++;
        if (found == allowableCommas) {
            return str.substring(0, comma) + str.substring(comma + 1).replaceAll(",", "");            
        }
        comma = str.indexOf(",", comma + 1);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through string, rebuilding using StringBuilder and checking for commas:

```
static String stripCommasAfterN(String s, int n)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(s.length());
    int commas = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = s.charAt(i);

        if (c == ',')
        {
            if (commas < n)
            {
                builder.append(c);
            }
            commas++;
        }
        else
        {
            builder.append(c);
        }
    }   

    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you could do,

**A**

1. Use split string to split the string into string arrays using `yourString.split(",")`.
2. Loop through the array of strings and add "," after the first 2 elements and just append the rest.

**B**

1. Find the location of the second comma using, indexOf()
2. split the string at this point.
3. Replace the "," with "" in the second substring and append it to the first.